# Change cell color on different values - Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I need to distinguish two consecutive cells.

Each one in a row, if they have different values, when databindind the values to a gridview.

So, if in the row 1 I have the cell "ABC" and in the row 2 I have the cell "CBA".

I need to color each cell with a different color.

What is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do it on the rowdatabound event of the gridview. Keep the previous row in viewstate or session and match it with the next row. If it does't match, change the color otherwise don't change.

Comment: This solutions works, using the viewstate to get the last row value. Thank you.

Answer (score 15):

This is called Conditional Formatting

You can enable the RowDataBound Event in the markup

```
<asp:GridView ID="gridview1" runat="server" OnRowDataBound="RowDataBound">

</asp:GridView>
```

And put this in your Code-Behind file.

```
protected void RowDataBound(Object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if(e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 0)     // This is row no.1
            if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "ABC")
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;

        if(e.Row.RowIndex == 1)     // This is row no.2
            if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "CBA")
                e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Green;
    }
}
```

Comment: This Solution worked for me by tweaking the code a bit. I did not use  if(e.Row.RowIndex == 0)   as my gridview always returns 1 row. I also used a for loop to traverse all the cells in my gridview

Answer (score 4):

Add to your gridview in html part of page OnRowDataBound="gridView1_DataBinding". And then add event handler codebehind:

```
protected void gridView1_DataBinding(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {

        if (e.Row.RowType != DataControlRowType.DataRow) return;

        var c = e.Row.FindControl("IdOfControl") as Label;
        if(c != null)
        {
            if (c.Text == "ABC")
                e.Row.BackColor = GetColor("Gray");

            if (c.Text == "BCA")
                e.Row.BackColor = GetColor("Green");
        }
    }

    private Color GetColor(string color)
    {
        return Color.FromName(color);
    }
```

Best regards, Dima.

Answer (score 2):

if i understand you right, you want to change the color of a cell, depending on it's value.
if that's correct, you could try it like this:

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        if ((Label)e.Row.Cells[0].FindControl("ValueHoldingControl").Text == "ABC")
        {
            //Coloring the cell
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
void gvShowFullDetail_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.BackColor = System.Drawing.ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#AECD6F");
        }
    }
```