# Gridview Eval function from code behind

Tags: asp.net

I'd like to avoid having an eval statement in each of the boundfields in the aspx page. Is there a way, perhaps at databind time, to evaluate the data in the code behind file instead? For instance, I'd like to display a blank if the actual data is 0.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is achieved by handling RowDataBound event which is called right after the data is bound to each row in the grid view.

Check my answer in this post [Change cell color on different values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427848/change-cell-color-on-different-values-gridview/4427945#4427945)

You could change these lines to something that suites your needs

```
if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "ABC")
    e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Red;
```

Maybe those would be

```
if(e.Row.Cells[0].Text == "0")
    e.Row.Cells[0].Text = string.Empty;
```

Answer (score 0):

Look here for more information on RowDataBound event: [More info](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx#Y500)