# Is it Possible to Change the text color for columns in Grid View based upon search item?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, html

**Note**: i need to change in different columns based upon search request.

Comment: please explain more of what you want

Comment: You might get your answer here

Visit http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427848/change-cell-color-on-different-values-gridview

Comment: The code you posted in a comment below, where in the code behind page is it?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can do it in `GridView.RowDataBound` event

Like this

```
protected void yourGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            e.Row.Cells[0].BackColor = Color.Beige;
            // 0 could be any valid cell index in your row
        }
    }
```

for more info [Go here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx)

Comment: i need to change the background of the particular cell in different pages. i am doing for this in reports.

Comment: For Ex: If i search with XYZ, i need to change the background color of that particular cell. Suppose if it in 1st and 10th pages i need to change it Or else if it is in Different columns also need to change the color. But it is happening in first page only. it is changing the color for the other pages.

Comment: Please provide some peace of code, so that I could understand what you have done. That would be helpful.

Comment: `foreach (GridViewRow gr in grdFlowInfo.Rows)

            {

                if (gr.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)

                {

                    for (int i = 0; i < gr.Cells.Count; i++)

                    {

                        if (((Label)gr.Cells[i].Controls[1]).Text.Trim().ToString() == txtSearch.Text.Trim().ToUpper())

                        {

                            gr.Cells[i].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;

                        }

                    }

                }

            }`

Comment: And in this code you have the problem that cell at 10th  page doesn't get colored but at 1st page does, am I right ??

Comment: Only it happens in First page.

Comment: Most probably your search `textbox` is loosing it's value or there could be case problem with your strings that you are trying to match, because `RowDataBound` event gets called during paging too so there no other reason for this to be on 1st page only, You should use breakpoints to debug your code and find the reason for that.