# How to chage the disabled hyperlink color in gridview?

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, rowdatabound

In `Gridview RowDataBound` I am disabling hyperlink based on its value. But hyperlink text is grayed out.
I want to change the fore color of the disabled hyperlink, so that I can read text easily.

I tried as mentioned below.

```
protected void gridResult_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) 
{       
    var hyperlink = e.Row.FindControl( "hlink" ) as HyperLink;
    if( hyperlink!= null && hyperlink.Text =="ABC" )
    {
        hyperlink.ForeColor = Color.Black;
        hyperlink.Enabled = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Might be the duplicate of [Change cell color on different values - Gridview][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427848/change-cell-color-on-different-values-gridview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd say add a `class` to the link instead of setting ForeColor and use CSS to style the disabled link.

```
hyperlink.CssClass = "disabledLink";
```

then in CSS:

```
.disabledLink {
  color: #000 !important;
}
```

Comment: I tried as you said, But it didn't solve my problem. It is still grayed out. I think we can't add css class to disabled hyperlinks.

Comment: Yes you can add a css class to a disabled `HyperLink`. It may be grayed out because .net places a css class `aspNetDisabled`, which your styles may be customizing. I added `!important` to the css so it overrides the current styles.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you really want to do is enable the TextBox and set the ReadOnly property to true.

It's a bit tricky to change the color of the text in a disabled TextBox. I think you'd probably have to subclass and override the OnPaint event.

Answer (score 0):

You can set the ForeColor by the CssClass property of HyperLink