# Group contents in GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have some n no of rows in my GridView. Those items are categorized into some categories.
For example first 10 rows are categorized into a category and second 7 rows are categorized into second category.

There is a column named category in the Binding DataTable. Basing on that column the gridview has to be divided into categories.

Grouping in my sense is Background color of the category has to be changed for particular category.

Comment: Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427848/change-cell-color-on-different-values-gridview

Answer (score 2):

You could create a CSS class for each of the categories that would set the background color that you want.  Then set the CSS class for each data row in your GridView in the RowDataBound event.

```
protected void MyGridView_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        e.Row.CssClass = ((MyDataClass) e.Row.DataItem).Category;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try using the templates of the ListView instead to avail of this grouping ability.

[ListView Grouping by Data Field](http://forums.asp.net/t/1532977.aspx/1)