# Color All Empty Cells in ASP.NET GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, gridview, cells

I was wondering if there is a way to color all the empty cells in a GridView in orange. The columns in my GridView are dynamically generated. Any help is appreciated.

Thanks!

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the rowtype is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {


        //loop all the cells in the row
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            int value = 0;

            //try converting the cell value to an int
            try
            {
                value = Convert.ToInt32(e.Row.Cells[i].Text);
            }
            catch
            {
            }

            //check the value and set the background color
            if (value == "")
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else 
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OnRowDataBound event is your starting point. There you can loop through all cells and check their value.

Comment: Look [HERE](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528633/how-to-change-gridview-cell-color-based-on-condition-using-c-sharp/31529889#31529889).

Comment: Can you show me exactly how you do it please?

Comment: I have cells with no values. How do you filter those?

Comment: Also, I am not exactly sure how many columns I will get, because the gridview is dynamic.

Comment: Try comparing it to `null`.

Comment: This is not helpful.

Comment: jstreet, can you look at my updated code and see what is wrong with it please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            if (e.Row.Cells[i].Text == "&nbsp;")
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Orange;
        }
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `RowDataBound` event for that, like you are doing now. But there is a problem. You create an `int value`, but then you try compare `value` to a string `if (value == "")`. that won't work.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    //check if the row is a datarow
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        //cast the row back to a datarowview
        DataRowView row = e.Row.DataItem as DataRowView;

        //loop all columns in the row
        for (int i = 0; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
        {
            //check if the string is null of empty in the source data
            //(row[i]) instead of e.Row.Cells[i].Text
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(row[i].ToString()))
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
            }
            else
            {
                e.Row.Cells[i].BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!