# How can a color-coded interpretation be provided based on the results?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a database containing specific information
I want to show some of the many values with their appropriate text values and have a special color
This is what I have and what I want it to appear in the browser
.
With love, thank you for your help

```
   public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
       if (!this.IsPostBack)
       {
           this.BindGrid();
       }
   }
   private void BindGrid()
   {
       {
           using (SqlDataAdapter sda = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT TOP 10 id, name, cood FROM test20 WHERE name NOT LIKE '%@%' ORDER BY id DESC", con))
           {       
               using (DataTable dt = new DataTable())
               {
                   sda.Fill(dt);
                   GridView1.DataSource = dt;
                   GridView1.DataBind();                                                           
               }
           }
       }
       GridView1.UseAccessibleHeader = true;
       GridView1.HeaderRow.TableSection = TableRowSection.TableHeader;
   }
}
```

[The current output is similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5mN8C.jpg)

[The desired output is similar to this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SukDd.jpg)

Comment: What's the issue you are facing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to change gridview cell color based on condition using C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31528633/how-to-change-gridview-cell-color-based-on-condition-using-c-sharp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, you don't say WHERE you plan to get these colors from?

I mean, there needs to be some logic for your colors. but, once you have some approach to setting colors, then the solution is rather easy.

Say, for example, I have a table of hotels.

For City = Jasper, I want green, and for Banff, I want say blue.

So, say this grid view:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName" />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="City"        HeaderText="City"  />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

And code to load the above grid?

```
   protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadGrid();
        }
    }

    void LoadGrid(string strCity = "")
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT * FROM tblHotels",
                         new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            GridView1.DataSource = cmdSQL.ExecuteReader();
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
    }
```

And output is thus this:

[image]

Now, to color? Well we can use  RowDataBound event, like this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            switch (e.Row.Cells[3].Text)
            {
                case "Jasper":
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    }

                case "Banff":
                    {
                        e.Row.Cells[3].ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
    }
```

And now our output looks like this:

[image]

However, you have left out the HUGE WHOPPER detail if your gv is using default columns, or boundfield columns? If yes, then above will work fine.

If you using templated columns, then a different approach is required.

So, assume City was a standard say label, like this:

```
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
            DataKeyNames="ID" CssClass="table table-hover" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound">
            <Columns>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="FirstName"   HeaderText="FirstName"   />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="LastName"    HeaderText="LastName"    />
                <asp:BoundField DataField="HotelName"   HeaderText="HotelName"   />
                <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("City") %>' > </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:BoundField DataField="Description" HeaderText="Description" />
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
```

Then our RowDatabound code looks like this:

```
       if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label txtCity = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("txtCity");

            switch (txtCity.Text)
            {
                case "Jasper":
                    {
                        txtCity.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
                        break;
                    }

                case "Banff":
                    {
                        txtCity.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
                        break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

Last but not least? If I had 20 different cities, and 20 different colors, of course one would NEVER hard code the color(s).

So, I would say make/have/create/use a table of Cities, and say what color I want, and join that in the query. In that case, then I would bind the grid using a table as you have, since the data source DURING the bind even can use any column from the data source. If you use ExecuteReader as I have done, then you are LIMITED TO ONLY columns in the grid, not other columns in the gv data source. (such as in this idea color). this means you DO WANT to bind the grid using a table as you have, if you are to use columns that don't appear in the grid (such as in this idea - the color would not be a column in the gv display, but it would be in the table data source, and thus can be used during the bind event).

***Edit ----------------------------------***

so, in place of hard coding the color in code, we can do this:

[image]

And of course we used colors from here:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_colors

Ok and now we simple LEFT join in the above color table to our query.

And note that we MUST use a table, since during data bind I need/want full use of the data row - EVEN FOR columns that I don't want to display. So in the following markup, I can NOW delete the city column, but STILL use City in the data bind even. (but, hey, lets just leave it for this post.

So, my markup columns are now this:

<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="City">

<asp:Label ID="txtCity" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("City") %>' Font-Bold="true"> </asp:Label>

</asp:TemplateField>

```
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Color">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="txtColor" runat="server" Text= '<%# Eval("Color") %>' Font-Bold="true"> </asp:Label>
                    </ItemTemplate>
```

(the rest is the same as before).

And now my query + data bind code is this:

```
        using (SqlCommand cmdSQL = new SqlCommand("SELECT *,Color FROM tblHotels "
            + "LEFT JOIN tblCityColors on tblHotels.City = tblCityColors.City " 
            + "ORDER BY HotelName",
                         new SqlConnection(Properties.Settings.Default.TEST3)))
        {
            cmdSQL.Connection.Open();
            DataTable rst = new DataTable();
            rst.Load(cmdSQL.ExecuteReader());
            GridView1.DataSource = rst;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }
```

And now our Row data bind event is this:

```
    protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
        {
            Label txtCity = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("txtCity");
            Label txtColor = (Label)e.Row.FindControl("txtColor");
            DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;

            txtColor.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(dr["Color"].ToString());
            txtCity.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromName(dr["Color"].ToString());
        }
    }
```

As noted, we could remove the city column from above - but for this demo, it is ok.

Now our output is this:

[image]

And NOTE VERY carful how we pick up the FULL data row during bind event with:

```
  DataRowView dr = (DataRowView)e.Row.DataItem;
```

So the GridView datasource is ONLY valid, and only active DURING the data binding events. Once the grid is rendered, then DataItem (for the row) or the GridView.DataSource is null and invalid - it only exists DURING the binding events, but that's all we need it for.

As a result, we can use any and all columns from the SQL - even ones NOT displayed in the grid.

Comment: thank you for replying
Yes, I benefited from your instructions and was able to change the color
I also want to change the many value in the name of the color, I don't want the number to appear
As in the example
The number 310 turns into the word (red) and is also in red.. and so on

Comment: Well, then you need some kind of translate table - see my above edit - I show how we can have many colors - not hard coded in code.