# Conditional formatting on an entire column in Gridview

Tags: c#, asp.net

I need to format 2 entire columns in my gridview based on if the cell contains the string "yes" or "no". I've looked everywhere trying to find something accomplishing what I'm trying to do and cant find anything based on a string, only int values.

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
    {
        GridView gv = (GridView)e.Row.FindControl("GridView2");
        var ds = new SqlDataSource();
        ds.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HUTDMSConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        ds.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM textBooks WHERE CourseID = '" + GridView1.DataKeys[e.Row.RowIndex].Value + "' ORDER BY BookTitle";
        gv.DataSource = ds;
        gv.DataBind();
    }
}
```

I know that the conditional formatting goes within the `gridview_rowdatabound` 
event.

What I have so far:

```
    protected void GridView2_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e) {
        if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == 0))
        {
            var valueFetched = ((TableCell)(e.Row.Cells[3].FindControl("no"))).Text;
            if (valueFetched == "no")
            {
                foreach (var cell in e.Row.Cells)
                    ((TableCell)cell).BackColor = Color.Red;
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change cell color on different values - Gridview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4427848/change-cell-color-on-different-values-gridview)

Answer (score 0):

Look at this example to get some direction.  This code goes under `RowDataBound`

```
if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && ((e.Row.RowState & DataControlRowState.Edit) == 0))
{
    var valueFetched = ((Label)(e.Row.Cells[1].FindControl("yourControlId"))).Text;
    if (valueFetched == "1")
    {
        foreach (var cell in e.Row.Cells)
            ((TableCell)cell).BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.LightBlue;
    }
}
```

Comment: in the var valueFetched is the e.row.Cells[1] referring to the first cell in each row?

Comment: yes, that is an index referring to the cell. You need to change that Index to  the column (index starts from 0); also the type cast is Label i my example; you may need to change to the control you have in that cell

Comment: Adding what I've done to my question. I put table cell in for label confused on that as well as my FindControl().text. I put "no" in because thats what I'm looking for but am confused on if thats what goes there or something else. i've tried a few different ways and nothing has worked yet.

Comment: my example expects you have some control on GridView with the name - yourControlId; I'll not be able to help if you don't provide complete information of how your GridView is laid out.